# Subscribe multiple documents with subCollections

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a list of documents from a collection called `assistantChats` which one has an attribute called `ref` with the reference to another document. This other document has attributes and a subCollection called `messages`. What I want is to subscribe to all documents referenced from `assistantChats` and its subCollections `messages`.

I've tried with `combineLatest()` but can just get the subscription or the document or the collection from the document, not all. How could I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

A query can only happen against a single collection at a time, or a collection group (which is not your case here).  If you want to listen to documents in multiple collections, you will need to make multiple queries and attach listeners/subscribers to each one of them separately.  There is no alternative.